# significance of __cpuinit and modpost warnings related to it

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What is the real significance of __cpuinit in the linux kernel code?
I have come across normal kernel code acceessing __cpuinit functions. This gives me loads of modpost warnings. Is this normal or a serious error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__cpuinit actually tells the compiler to put the function into the specified elf section.

```
#define __cpuinit        __section(.cpuinit.text) __cold
```

the kernel code says in include/linux/init.h:

```
 /* modpost check for section mismatches during the kernel build.
 * A section mismatch happens when there are references from a
 * code or data section to an init section (both code or data).
 * The init sections are (for most archs) discarded by the kernel
 * when early init has completed so all such references are potential bugs.
 * For exit sections the same issue exists.  ......
```